# How to recode a date using Sys.Date() or today() into a string or factor in R?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, data-manipulation, lubridate

As part of an automation process, I have a df with a date variable. There are only two date levels today and yesterday.
I am looking to recode this date variable so that todays and yesterdays dates in %d-%m-%Y
format

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date2 = recode(date, "today" = Sys.Date(), "yesterday" = Sys.Date()-1))
```

This returns an error:
Error in UseMethod("recode") : 
  no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "Date"

I would be really grateful for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want? Using a case_when to check if the date equals today(), and if so, classifying as 'today', otherwise classifying as 'yesterday'?

```
df %>% 
mutate(date2 = case_when(
date==lubridate::today() ~ "Today",
TRUE ~ "Yesterday"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. The date variable only has 2 dates. I wanted to convert todays date to the factor represented as "today" and the same for yesterday. I tried to amend it using today() or Sys.Date(). Even if I could recode it as max(date) = "today" and min(date) = "yesterday" - df %>% mutate(date2, max(date) = "today", min(date) = "yesterday")  ,but this doesnt work either. Im sure its pretty straight forward but I cant seem to come up with an answer